# Is the Windows 8 path variable supposed to be this long?

Tags: windows, windows-8, environment-variables

I have Windows 8 and my `Path` variable seems like it's way longer than it's supposed to be (I'm just starting to figure environment variables and stuff out, and trying to change my Path so that I can use Java [i.e. change the path to incorporate the JDK]).

This is what my Path was/is set as:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\`

Is that what it should be? If it's not, any ideas as to *why* it's this way?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your question still not answered?

Answer (score 3):

The PATH variable is used to be able to use programs without typing the entire path they're contained in, like you're trying to do with JDK. Some programs add stuff to it upon installation, which isn't harmful to my knowledge.

I wouldn't remove any of them, as that might break stuff. Just add a semicolon and the path to JDK. I think you have to log off and on again for it to take effect, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the entries of this path are required by Intel software in order to different features of chipset can run. This in common in laptops with new Intel´s chipsets. Although Intel has done a little sloppy when it is needed to include as many entries. 
More information here:

http://www.shouldiremoveit.com/Intel-Management-Engine-Components-5127-program.aspx
https://communities.intel.com/thread/46711